# Retrieve a value from SQLParameter in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to retrieve a value from a List.  The list is already filled but I keep getting an error saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I try to execute this code:

I created a global variable

```
private static readonly string _isDevItemParamName = "@DevItem";
```

In my method I call:

```
var devItem = sqlParams.Where(p => p.ParameterName == _isDevItemParamName).First();
```

This is where the error seems to occur when I do breakpoints.

Comment: obviously there is no parameter `@DevItem` try `FirstOrDefault()` instead and `var devItem ` will be null

Comment: do you have @DevItem in sqlParams list?

Comment: This query can be shortened to :  `var devItem = sqlParams.First(p => p.ParameterName == _isDevItemParamName);` But keep in mind that `First()` throws an exception if no such a value can be found whilst `FirstOrDefault()` returns default value.

Comment: There is a @DevItem in the List.  It is a 0 or 1 returned from the query.  I should have stated that, my apologies.

Comment: Could it be that the `@` is redundant? Meaning you should look for `DevItem` instead of `@DevItem`?

Comment: Try debugging and inspect the `ParameterName` of the items in `sqlParams` to make sure there is a match.

Comment: The ParameterName does exist, I verified that with breakpoints.  It is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check sqlParams is null or contains any parameters and also use firstordefault instead of first because if the parameter is not available it should not through any exception.